# Using HTML to submit a form if JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search box that uses jQuery to submit the user's search and then display the results. However, for users that have JavaScript disabled this would not work so I have put the search box as a form so it will still work just by loading a different page instead.

However, now when I try and submit a search with JavaScript enabled it just submits the form and loads a new page as it would when JavaScript is disabled.

How can I resolve this? I hope you can understand my question.

I currently use the following jQuery code to submit my form:

```
$("#s").keyup(function(b){
if(b.keyCode==13){
if($(this).val().length>0){
```

And I have the following HTML:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
<input type="text" id="s" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(Event) {
    Event.preventDefault();
    // Do your AJAX fancy submit stuff
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you delete and re-add?

Return false should be enough. The following would run on this page will prevent the stackoverflow search from firing.

```
$("#search').submit(function(){ return false;});
```

In your case:  `$('#s').parent().submit(function(){ return false;});`